# Does $\hat{\beta}=(X′X)^{−1}X′ \ Y$ simplify further?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, least-squares

As far as I know $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$ and matrix multiplication is associative so:

$$(X′ X)^{−1}X′=(X^{-1})(X')^{-1}(X')=X^{-1}.$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: there is usually no $X^{-1}$ because the data matrix is rarely square

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The matrix $(X'X)^{-1} X'$ is the [Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) of the design matrix $X$, which is a generalisation of the concept of the inverse.  If the design matrix is an invertible square-matrix then the pseudo-inverse is equal to the inverse, and your working holds.  However, it is generally the case that the design matrix *is not a square matrix and therefore does not have an inverse*.

Remember that the rule $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$ holds only when $A$ and $B$ are invertible square matrices.  The matrix $X$ is not generally square, so this matrix and its transpose have no inverse at all, so in this case your working does not hold.